# Labview my modulated signal is in frequency?

Tags: labview

I am working on understanding modulation and demodulation when I ran into a rather weird problem with my graphs. It seems the spectrum of my modulated signal is shown in time while my signal was shown in frequency. Is there something I did wrong in the setup? Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `Spectrum of Modulated Signal` is in the frequency domain, but the X-Axis is just the number of non-redundant points in FFT and not scaled to a normalized frequency.

Check the `Spectral Measurements` VI that is attached to `Spectrum of Modulated Signal` and adjust the settings to get it to a normalized frequency.  You can change the X-Axis label to read `Frequency` instead of `Time`, but that is cosmetic (and proper).

Comment: To change the label of your X axis, right click on the graph(or the chart) and select "Properties". Then go to "Scales" tab and change the X label.